# Unable to install packages in Ubuntu 14.04 LTS from apt-get

Tags: 14.04, apt, package-management, dpkg

So I have been trying to install `freeglut3-dev` for Ubuntu 14.04 LTS, but whenever I type in the terminal command, I get the following error (the same is happening whenever I'm trying to install other packages as well) -

```
rohitrango@rohitrango-G551JX:~$ sudo apt-get install freeglut3-dev
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree 
Reading state information... Done
freeglut3-dev is already the newest version.
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
linux-headers-4.4.0-34 linux-headers-4.4.0-34-generic
linux-image-4.4.0-34-generic linux-image-extra-4.4.0-34-generic
linux-signed-image-4.4.0-34-generic
Use 'apt-get autoremove' to remove them.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 1 not upgraded.
4 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] 
Setting up click (0.4.21.1ubuntu0.2) ...
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/usr/bin/click", line 31, in <module>
from click import commands
ImportError: cannot import name 'commands'
dpkg: error processing package click (--configure):
subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of click-apparmor:
click-apparmor depends on click; however:
Package click is not configured yet.
dpkg: error processing package click-apparmor (--configure):
dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of upstart-app-launch:
upstart-app-launch depends on click-apparmor; however:
Package click-apparmor is not configured yet.
dpkg: error processing package upstart-app-launch (--configure):
dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of upstart-app-launch-tools:
upstart-app-launch-tools depends on upstart-app-launch (= 0.3+14.04.20140411-0ubuntu1); however:
Package upstart-app-launch is not configured yet.
dpkg: error processing package upstart-app-launch-tools (--configure):
dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because the error message indicates its a followup error from a previous failure.
No apport report written because the error message indicates its a followup error from a previous failure.
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
Errors were encountered while processing:
click
click-apparmor
upstart-app-launch
upstart-app-launch-tools
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
rohitrango@rohitrango-G551JX:~$
```

So what I tried was to remove the `sl` package from my system to see if I received the same error. And I did, but here, the package was actually removed. I'm not an expert so I don't really know what's happening.

Any help is highly appreciated! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The log above says: "freeglut3-dev is already the newest version."
so you have this app in your system also it says there are packages not use and which could be deleted.
I would recommend you to update system first

```
sudo apt update
```

then install updates

```
sudo apt upgrade
```

install system updates

```
sudo apt dist-upgrade
```

install missed dependencies

```
sudo apt install -f
```

and then clean unnecessary packages

```
sudo apt-get autoremove
sudo apt-get autoclean
```

Now try to install something.

Comment: I updated as you said, but the upgrade and dist-upgrade fails, it simply shows the same errors and terminates after showing a bar showing 0% progress.

What I don't understand is that I never messed around with the `usr/bin` but then how did it get this ugly.